# Cocoa App Enter Full Screen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am developing a simple application which make use of full screen window.

Window contains view that contains button, image etc etc... , but when I enter in full screen with the follow lines:

```
NSWindow* tmp = [self window];
    [tmp setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
    [tmp setFrame:[tmp frameRectForContentRect:[[tmp screen] frame]]display:YES animate:NO];
    [tmp setBackingType:NSBackingStoreBuffered];
    screenRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
    int windowLevel = CGShieldingWindowLevel();
    [self.window setLevel:windowLevel];
```

The view I put in the window doesn't resized automatically, I could make some operation for resize correctly that work, but there are a way to do that automatically?

I post all my AppController here:

```
 -(id)init {
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindow"];

    NSWindow* tmp = [self window];
    [tmp setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
    [tmp setFrame:[tmp frameRectForContentRect:[[tmp screen] frame]]display:YES animate:NO];
    [tmp setBackingType:NSBackingStoreBuffered];
    screenRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];

  /**   
   //  [[tmp standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton] setHidden:YES];
   //  [[tmp standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton] setHidden:YES];

    self.window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:screenRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO screen:[NSScreen mainScreen]];
  **/
    int windowLevel = CGShieldingWindowLevel();
    [self.window setLevel:windowLevel];
    return self;
}


// We need to be layer-backed to have subview transitions.
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [[self window] setContentSize:[topMenu frame].size];
    [[[self window] contentView] addSubview:topMenu];
    [topMenu enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen] withOptions:nil];
    [[[self window] contentView] setWantsLayer:YES];
}


- (void)dealloc
{

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.


    [topMenu_controller performAnimation]; 
    return;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the springs and struts of Interface Builder to set a view's autosizing behavior:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/Layout/Layout.html

Comment: The link is out of date, I have to search Layout?

Comment: You need to set the sizing attributes for the view so that it keeps the same proportions as the window. Select the view in Interface Builder and choose Tools → Show Inspector, then select Size from the dropdown at the top of the inspector window. The bottom half of the inspector window contains a section labeled Autosizing. These are called "springs and struts." 

Click the horizontal and vertical lines in the internal box so that they change to springs. This will cause the text view's internal size to grow and shrink with the window.

Comment: [Here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20100901161944/http://developer.apple.com:80/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/Layout/Layout.html) an archived version of that documentation, and [here's](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1) some documentation explaining Apple's newer layout engine, Auto Layout.